# traverse through every word in paragraph jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a paragraph

```
 <div id="unique"> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

I want to get each word inside this paragraph. I already tried doing

```
 var $texts = $("#unique");
 $texts.each(function(i, text){
 var str = $(text).text();
    console.log(text);
 });
```

But this only gives me the whole text "Lorem ipsum dolor" and not "Lorem","ipsum" and "dolor". Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Use `split` method `str.split(' ')`.

Comment: Why do you expect `.each()` to do something that [the API docs](http://api.jquery.com/each) do not describe?

Comment: and I don't see any sense on using `each` on an ID element, or I missed the party?

Comment: @roXon the OP simply does not understand what `.each()` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the string prototype `.split()`.

```
$.each($('#unique').text().split(' '), function(i, text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can stick to standard JavaScript, which will be a lot faster than accessing jQuery methods:

```
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor';
var arr = str.split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   var word = arr[i];
   console.log(word);
}
```

Here are some [benchmark tests](http://jsperf.com/js1-vs-jquery-iteration) which show that using jQuery proves to be **8% slower**:

```
Normal JS = 13,668 Ops/sec (±1.00% - fastest) 
jQuery = 12,442 Ops/sec (±0.43% - 8% slower)
```

Comment: Don't use for-in for arrays!

Comment: I've repeatedly read exhortations to not use `for ... in` but never seen a comprehensive analysis of why not. Regardless, I've changed the iteration. It'll still be **a lot quicker** than not using jQuery.

Comment: There are two reasons: First, the iteration order is not guaranteed. Second, if you add any methods to Array.prototype, these will show up on iteration. This actually caused a bug on IE8 _only_ in an application I was maintaining.

Comment: The bottleneck in your code is `console.log`; if you use some more lightweight loop body, the difference should be much more pronounced - see r#2 - the difference is _dramatic_.